# How to use STRING_SPLIT() in a update query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a table, One of its fields is a comma-separated value, I want to update that table, I tried different code but not working

```
UPDATE [PATS].[ReportSubscription]
   SET [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
      ,[ReferenceID] = @ReferenceID
      ,[ReferenceType] = @ReferenceType
      ,[Schedule] = @Schedule
      ,[Day] = @Day
      ,[Time] = @Time
      ,[ProjectID] = @ProjectID
      ,[LastSentDate] = @LastSentDate
      ,[UserID] = @UserID
      --,[CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy
      --,[CreatedDate] = @CreatedDate
      ,[UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy
      ,[UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate
  WHERE ID=@ID AND @Day IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))
```

I think this `(SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))` should be joined with the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be selecting `value` from the table returned by `STRING_SPLIT`:

```
WHERE ID=@ID AND [Day] IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))
```

Also, you should be comparing the table's column `[Day]` against the CSV list, *not* the variable `@Day`.

But, it is usually not a good idea to mix CSV data with SQL databases.  Consider storing your CSV list of days in a separate table if possible.

Comment: what to do if we need to insert a new entry of this if a new day in added for the row,i think i should add a insert query with it. right

Comment: I think you should join to a separate table containing the days, and then just maintain that table as you need.

Comment: i will add a sample of my table here

Comment: i have added the table here, here take first row im going to update and its Day is **Fri** now, the i add **Mon** with **Fri**, then i need to update the row with **Fri** as it is and **Mon** as a new row with new **ID** and all other same

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the data in the variable has space.
You should be selecting `value` from the table returned by `STRING_SPLIT` and triming value for use in condition, for example:

```
DECLARE @day NVARCHAR(500) = N'12 , 25,    41,54   ,89'
IF '41' IN (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))
    PRINT('Ok')
ELSE
    PRINT('Not Found')

-- printed : 'Ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be:

```
UPDATE [PATS].[ReportSubscription]
   SET [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
  ,[ReferenceID] = @ReferenceID
  ,[ReferenceType] = @ReferenceType
  ,[Schedule] = @Schedule
  ,[Day] = @Day
  ,[Time] = @Time
  ,[ProjectID] = @ProjectID
  ,[LastSentDate] = @LastSentDate
  ,[UserID] = @UserID
  ,[CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy
  ,[CreatedDate] = @CreatedDate
  ,[UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy
  ,[UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate
  WHERE ID=@ID AND Day IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))
```

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for more info. 
Note: Make sure to trim your selection for **unwanted spaces** accordingly!